# change CSS of sibling when our element have <a> Tag

Tags: css, css-selectors, dotnetnuke

I purchased a DotNetNuke log in module and Want to change appearance of this module.
When a user login in my site an html like this will be generated:

```
<div id="Login">
<div id="HelloLogin">Hello</div>
<a href="http://localhost:6111/en-us/userprofile.aspx">mosijava</a>
</div>
```

But when (s)he log out, the html goes like bellow and `<a>` tag will not generate:

```
<div id="Login">
<div id="HelloLogin">Hello</div>
guest
</div>
```

I want to assign a css to div with ID="HelloLogin", ONLY when a user login. it means when I have `<a>` tag in my html.

is there any pure css way to do it?

I tried this selector but it didn't work

```
#login a:before{
color:red;
}
```

Comment: Looks like BoltClock's answer is the best as far as pure CSS but has compatibility issues.  My solution would be to either A. If you have access to the code simply add a check if the user is logged in and if so set a new style or inline style for `HelloLogin` or B. You'll have to do it via Javascript by basically getting the element Login and either checking for the text guest or check if it has 2 child elements (the `div` and `a` elements) and then apply a style to HelloLogin through Javascript.

Comment: I'd just add to @Jeff's answer that even if you don't have the code for the login module, you could add something in your skin to add a CSS Class to the pane when the user is authenticated.  Something like `<div id="LoginPane" runat="server" class='<%#If(Request.IsAuthenticated, "logged-in", "logged-out") %>'></div>` assuming that your skin is set with VB as the language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no previous sibling selector in CSS, so you won't be able to write something similar to what you've tried. The `:before` pseudo-element works differently than you'd expect.

In this special case, though, you can use CSS3's `:not()` and `:only-child` pseudo-classes with the IDs, so it'll match only when `#HelloLogin` is *not* the only child element in `#Login` (inline text, like the word "guest" in your example, doesn't count as children/siblings in CSS):

```
#Login #HelloLogin:not(:only-child) {
    color: red;
}
```

The problem is that IE < 9 doesn't support `:not()` or `:only-child`, but there's no other way to do it in pure CSS.